# Error Handling in flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

Loading a file in flex prompt for error called  Error #2044: Unhandled IOErrorEvent:. text=Error #2124: Loaded file is an unknown type. 
What i need to do is when this error occurs i want to call a function.
So i put the block of code causing an error occurrence in try catch block.
But when error occurred it does not come in catch.
Below is snippet of code.

```
try {
    var loader:Loader = new Loader();
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaderCompleteHandler);
    loader.loadBytes(fileReferance.data);   
}
catch(err:*) {
    functionTocall(fileReferance);
}
```

How to handle it..

Answer (score 6):

There are 2 types of errors in flash: synchronous and asynchronous. Synchronous errors can be handled with `try..catch` block. Such errors are thrown immediately, when code execution fails. But you can't know exactly, when asynchronous error will be thrown. You're trying to handle asynchronous error. That's why you cannot catch it the way you do it.
You should add event listener for [IOErrorEvent](http://help.adobe.com/ru_RU/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/IOErrorEvent.html).

```
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onIOError);
...
private function onIOError(e:IOErrorEvent) {
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just add another listener which is listening for the `IOErrorEvent`:

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaderCompleteHandler);
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, loaderErrorHandler);
loader.loadBytes(fileReferance.data);
```

that's it